# Will App Store Update Erase Core Data/NSUserDfeaults?

Tags: swift, core-data, app-store, nsuserdefaults

My app uses Core Data to store multiple entries, and NSUserDefaults to store a value. If I publish an update to the app store, will it erase that info? I have not adjusted the code for the Core Data; however, I added code for a nil/non-existent case for the NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, updating an app does not erase the app's data, even if the app uses Core Data or `NSUserDefaults`. Deleting and reinstalling an app removes app data stored on the device, but doesn't touch any cloud data the app may have stored.